# `std::string::substr` returning invalid pointer?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, substring, std

I'm writing a function to split a C++ `string` into two separate `string`s, based on the location of a specific character. However, when I use the pointers it returns, they seem to be invalid. Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool SplitString(std::string &input, char splitChar, std::string **left, std::string **right)
{
    std::string::size_type offset = input.find(splitChar);
    if (offset == std::string::npos) return false;
    *left = &input.substr(0, offset);
    *right = &input.substr(offset + 1);
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string input = "Left side:Right side";
    std::string *left;
    std::string *right;

    if (SplitString(input, ':', &left, &right)) {
        std::cout << "left = \"" << *left << "\"" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "right = \"" << *right << "\"" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Didn't find ':' - this shouldn't happen!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This should output the following:

```
left = "Left side"
right = "Right side"
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: Why don't you just send a reference to a string to those functions?  Why all the pointer madness?

Comment: That's what you get for taking the address of an rvalue.

Comment: stdd::string::substr does not return a std::string*, it returns an std::string. You're getting the address of a returned value and when you call your second std::string::substr, it is being overwritten. Just copy the string. Get rid of all those pointers and just use std::string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need pointers here. You can take `left` and `right` by reference. Arguably, you don't need to take `input` by reference (you don't modify it, and if you did, what if you had to perform other manipulations on the same input?) So either pass it by value (if you intend to work on a copy) or `const&` (to signify the intent to not modify it).

```
bool SplitString(std::string input, char splitChar, std::string& left, std::string& right)
{
    std::string::size_type offset = input.find(splitChar);
    if (offset == std::string::npos) return false;
    left = input.substr(0, offset);
    right = input.substr(offset + 1);
    return true;
}

// ...

    std::string left;
    std::string right;

    if (SplitString(input, ':', left, right)) {

// ...
```

Comment: Why choose pass by value for input as your default?

Comment: the method `std::string::substr` do constructing a new string as result, which will be destroyed when exiting the function, thus, we'd copy the result before exiting the function. BTW, the argument `input` can be a reference too.

Answer (score -6):

Turns out when I compiled my test code with `g++`, it gave me a warning that the Visual C++ compiler didn't give me. The problem is that the object returned by `std::string::substr` is considered "temporary" and isn't valid when used outside of the function. The solution was, instead of `*left = &input.substr(0, offset)`, to use `*left = new std::string(input.substr(0, offset))`. Obviously modify the `*right` line in a similar manner.

Don't forget to `delete` the new objects when you're done with them!

Here's the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool SplitString(std::string &input, char splitChar, std::string **left, std::string **right)
{
    std::string::size_type offset = input.find(splitChar);
    if (offset == std::string::npos) return false;
    *left = new std::string(input.substr(0, offset));
    *right = new std::string(input.substr(offset + 1));
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string input = "Left side:Right side";
    std::string *left;
    std::string *right;

    if (SplitString(input, ':', &left, &right)) {
        std::cout << "left = \"" << *left << "\"" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "right = \"" << *right << "\"" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Didn't find ':' - this shouldn't happen!" << std::endl;
    }

    delete left;
    delete right;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course it's a temporary; you never assigned it to anything.  `substr` returns a string.  You took the address of that return value and discarded the value itself.  And why in the world would you `new` up a string anyway?  Just take references and assign the result of `substr`.  Let the `string` do its job and handle memory allocation for you. On (another) side note, there are better ways to split a string.  Use `std::getline`.

Comment: Please explain what this code does: `delete left, right;`

Comment: Oh! Thanks, @TheDark. I'll go ahead and fix that, but if that's why I was being downvoted, can you please undo it? I posted this question even after I figured it out so I could answer it and hopefully help people, and I'd rather not lose reputation because of that!

Also, thanks for the suggestion on doing it by reference.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are being downvoted so harshly. Even though remyabel's answer is much better, adding your own solution should be encouraged as far as I am concerned. I just commented to let you know it needed fixing.